# Showing a notice when site fails to load completely

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Sometimes during overload some sites fail to load.

I can detect this error using  chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred api.

I guess the content script will not run at all in this case so sending message from background page to content script is of no use.

**How can I paste a notice in the site body that it has failed to load?**

Maybe using script execute from the background page? Will the page have a body content?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onErrorOccurred)?

Comment: @dan75 No I've n't

Comment: by default it'll fire every time an error occurs on any request (document, stylesheet, image, etc). However, if you use it with a [resource type filter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-ResourceType) then you could filter for certain requests types.

Comment: @dan75 ok I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options here. If you're using `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred()` though I'd suggest you redirect the tab to an error page when an error occurs, using `chrome.tabs.update()`.

For example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function(details) 
{    
    chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: "URL FOR AN ERROR PAGE"});
},
{types: ["main_frame"]});
```

This will redirect the tab the error occurred in when a web request with a [resourceType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-ResourceType) of main_frame errors.

There are a few things you need to consider here. Do you only want to capture errors from requests with a type of main_frame? If not, just remove the 'types' filter from the event.

The other thing you need to consider is what page you're redirecting to. You can package a HTML file within your extension and then redirect to that. To generate the URL of your error page you can run `chrome.extension.getURL('customerrorpage.html')`.